# Unclosed character class in Java semver regex

Tags: regex, string, java-8, semantic-versioning

Java 8 here. I'm being passed a `String` and I need to tell if it matches our interval rendition of a semantically-versioned JAR file or not, which:

- Starts with any alphanumeric string (hyphens also allowed here)
- Followed by a hypen (`-`)
- Followed by normal semver:

  - Major release number; then
  - Minor release number; then
  - Patch number
- Ending with a suffix of `.jar`

Examples of valid file names:

- `some-lib-1.4.17.jar`
- `someLib-1.4.17.jar`
- `somelib-0.12.0.jar`

My best attempt thus far:

```
public boolean isValidJarName(String jarName) {
    String fileRegex = "^([a-zA-Z\\-))((\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)).jar";
    Pattern filePattern = Pattern.compile(fileRegex);
    Matcher matcher = filePattern.matcher(jarName);

    return matcher.matches();
}
```

However this gives me a compiler error: `Unclosed character class`. So something is wrong with my regex syntactically, but then I'm not even sure if its set up correctly to give me what I'm looking for. Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Comment: there is the closing `]` missing for `[`. So i guess it should be ` String fileRegex = "^([a-zA-Z\\-]))((\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)).jar";`

Comment: There seems to be a typo where you wrote `)` instead of `]` in the regex and your character class got left unclosed. Try using this `^([a-zA-Z\\-])((\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)).jar`

Comment: Thanks @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi (+1) that gets rid of the compiler error but still all my examples fail to match (e.g. `someLib-1.2.3.jar` resolves to false on `matcher.matches("someLib-1.2.3.jar")`, etc.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup: There are some issues further in your regex. Let me clarify through an answer.

Comment: `"([a-zA-Z\\-]+)-(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+).jar"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides that unclosed character class, there seems some more issues in your current regex,

```
^([a-zA-Z\\-))((\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)).jar
```

If your intent is to just match, you don't need to unnecessarily group the regex and amount of grouping is heavy. Also you don't need to escape `-` while it is inside character class and is present either at start or end of the character class. Since your string has `someLib` which is more than one character, hence you need to have quantifier with character class and you need to escape last dot just before `jar` otherwise it may match any character which may not be desirable. The correct regex you can use is following,

```
^[a-zA-Z-]+\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.jar
```

Here is the Java code,

```
String jarName = "someLib-1.2.3.jar";
String fileRegex = "^[a-zA-Z-]+\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.jar";
Pattern filePattern = Pattern.compile(fileRegex);
Matcher matcher = filePattern.matcher(jarName);

System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

This now prints,

```
true
```

Also, you can write your regex more compactly like this to match the given text,

```
^[a-zA-Z]+-(\\d+\\.)+jar
```

Where `[a-zA-Z]+` matches one or more alphabets, `-` matches a hyphen, `(\\d+\\.)+` matches one or more digits followed by literal dot and whole of it one or more times, then finally `jar` matches literal `jar`

Comment: From the description, I’d conclude that the hyphen between the base name and the version number is supposed to be mandatory, so there should be another `-` after `[a-zA-Z-]+`. Without it, it still matches all examples, but also, e.g. `"foo1.2.3.jar"`.

Comment: @Holger: I totally agree with you, which is why I deliberately didn't remove hyphen from the first regex solution. In fact, an even better regex should be `^([a-zA-Z]+-)+(\\d+\\.)+jar` so it can match well texts like `someLib-version-1.2.3.jar` and not just match something like just `----1.2.3.jar` And of course, the regex can further be improved, based upon more valid/invalid samples.

Comment: Then, it would be recommended to use `([a-zA-Z]++-)++`, to avoid backtracking.

Comment: @Holger: Yes, again agree with you as that would make the regex faster. Thanks for suggesting it.